# Resize page height to fit content after navigating to different page

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on an extension right now. I have it so that I have a small menu page, and then on button click, we navigate to one of my pages (which has a long list of things). When we do that, the entire page stretches vertically to accommodate as much of the info as possible. I also have a back button that navigates back to the menu (I'm using React, so this is done by React Routers). However, I only have, say, 3 items in the menu. This makes the page look a bit awkward as there are only 3 items (aligned center vertically) in the entire page, but the height is quite massive. I tried using `h-fit` and `max-h-fit` (using Tailwind), but it doesn't work. Here's the CSS for the 2 things:

```
        <div className="flex flex-col h-fit max-h-fit">
                <Button onClick={() => console.log("logout")} text="logout" />
                <Button onClick={() => handleLink()} text="link" />            
        </div>
```

```
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center align-top">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search" 
                className="focus:outline-none px-3 py-2 bg-inherit text-orange-400" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}/>

            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center m-auto">
                {links.map((value, index) => {
                    return (search == '' || value['name'].includes(search)) ?
                        <div className={linkIndex == index ? "text-orange-400 my-1 px-1" : "text-white my-1 px-1"} 
                            onClick={(e) => setIndex(index)}>
                            {value['name']}
                        </div> : <div></div>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Not sure what I can do to change this